# Using nio.relativize for a normalized path

Tags: java, path, nio

Normally, a path ignores all the `.` (this directory) it contains. So, `c:\\personal\\.\\photos\\readme.txt` and `c:\\personal\\photos\\readme.txt` should give identical results for different operations, but in the following code, the normalized path gives a different result. Can anyone explain the reason for this?

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("c:\\personal\\.\\photos\\readme.txt"); 
Path p2 = Paths.get("c:\\personal\\index.html"); 
Path p3 = p1.relativize(p2); 
System.out.println(p3);

p1 = p1.normalize();
p2 = Paths.get("c:\\personal\\index.html"); 
p3 = p1.relativize(p2); 
System.out.println(p3);
```

Output:

```
..\..\..\index.html
..\..\index.html
```

Comment: I just ran it with Java 11 and the output was 2 times _..\..\index.html_ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path class itself does not ignore **\\.** by default. It happens when you explicitly ask through normalize(). Here in oracle documentation on path's relativize method

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize(java.nio.file.Path) ***For example, if this path is "/a/b" and the given path is "/a/x" then the resulting relative path may be "../x".***

So the answer might be that, path does not by default discards **\\.**. Which along with oracle documentation results the output you see.